# Why is there no official doc on JSF <f:ajax /> tag

Tags: jsf

I went to what I think is supposed to be the official javadoc for JSF 2.0 : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/jsp/index.html

And I don't see the `f:ajax` tag.. How come?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're reading the **JSP** targeted docs, not the **Facelets** targeted docs. Replace the "/jsp" path near the end of URL by "/facelets" to get the [proper](http://docs.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html) docs.

Note that more proper ("official") URLs of the JSF tag documentations are the following:

- JSF 1.2: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/
- JSF 2.0: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/
- JSF 2.1: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/